# Should I precompile assets locallly before deployment on on the server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I have the option to precompile my assets locally in development or on my production server. I deploy with git, so I'd prefer not to have to check in all these assets (especially if they're using cache-busting digests).

Is there any advantage to precompiling assets locally (other than lacking write-access on the production machine)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site doesn't need to be down when you precompile assets. If you use capistrano or similar tools, you precompile the assets in the server, then (after this and more steps have been completed) restart the app. Meanwhile the app is being served from the old code (and assets).

On the other side, I disagree about the "cache-busting" comment. Git is smart enough to understand a diff between two differently named files if possible. So the result would be exactly the same whether the names changed or not. In which case I completely agree that it's nonsensical to load the repository with generated data, like compiled assets.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that compiling assets locally is much faster and then your site is down for a shorter period.

Of course, that depends on your server setup etc...

Comment: is there an advantage of doing it in dev environment regarding finding a missing configuration? sometimes one misses to define a new asset in the config file for the asset compilation and in our case this shows up on production (because we compile at production server)